# How do I export my fastai resnet50/vision_learner trained model into torchserve?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, fast-ai, torchserve

My goal is to deploy a model I trained with Fastai into Torchserve. I was following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/deploy-fast-ai-trained-pytorch-model-in-torchserve-and-host-in-amazon-sagemaker-inference-endpoint/) but got stuck on the part where he created the model class for pytorch.

He mentions that to run our model in Torchserve, and we need the following:

1. A model class
2. The weights exported from pytorch (a pth file)
3. A handler

Out of these, I get two: the weights and the handler. However, where I'm stuck is in the model class. He created one class file, but I have no idea where he got the **DynamicUnet** to use as a base for the class or how he mixed that class with **unet_learner** to create a custom pytorch model class. Can you help me build a model class for a model trained under the learner **vision_learner** and the pre-trained model of **resnet50**?

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix myself. Turns out you can just go into the ??create_vision_model and then the ??add_head and put them as the model class inside of the "initialize" function inside of the handler.py ; you should end up with something like this:

```
state_dict = torch.load(model_pt_path, map_location=self.device)
head = None
concat_pool = True
pool = True
lin_ftrs = None
ps = 0.5
first_bn = True
bn_final = False
lin_first = False
y_range = None
init = nn.init.kaiming_normal_
arch = resnet50
n_out = 9
pretrained = True
cut = None
n_in = 3
custom_head = None
# self.model = MyVisionModel()
meta = model_meta.get(arch, _default_meta)
model = arch(pretrained=pretrained)
body = create_body(model, n_in, pretrained, ifnone(cut, meta['cut']))
nf = num_features_model(nn.Sequential(*body.children())) if custom_head is None else None
if head is None:
    head = create_head(nf, n_out, concat_pool=concat_pool, pool=pool,
                       lin_ftrs=lin_ftrs, ps=ps, first_bn=first_bn, bn_final=bn_final, lin_first=lin_first,
                       y_range=y_range)
self.model = nn.Sequential(body, head)
self.model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
self.model.to(self.device)
self.model.eval()

logger.debug("Model file {0} loaded successfully".format(model_pt_path))
self.initialized = True
```